# Basemap windbarbs loading netCDF files

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to plot wind barbs onto a map using basemap.
I have two netCDF files, and the example I'm using from a previous assignment has me using a zipped numpy file. Is there a way to convert netCDF to numpy? Or do i just regularly zip the files? My error is it is not reading the file properly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from IPython.display import Image
from IPython.core.display import HTML 
plt.clf()
#Initiate a Basemap instance with the Lambert Conformal Conic projection and the specified bounds and resolution arguments.  Draw states, coastlines, and countries on the map. 
m = Basemap  (projection='lcc',lon_0=-92,lat_0=38,llcrnrlat=23.5,urcrnrlat=50,llcrnrlon=-107,urcrnrlon=-71,resolution='l',area_thresh=1000)  #Makes map window
V =np.load('042711_V.nc') #Load uandv.npz, a zipped NumPy file
U =np.load('042711_U.nc') #Load uandv.npz, a zipped NumPy file
x =np.transpose(V['x']) #Load x locations from zipped NumPy array
y =np.transpose(V['y']) #Load y locations from zipped NumPy array
u =np.transpose(V['u']) #Load u-component of velocity from zipped NumPy array
v =np.transpose(V['v']) #Load v-component of velocity from zipped NumPy array
cs=plt.contour(h, levels = range(5400,6000,60), colors = 'black') #Create contour map
plt.clabel(cs,fmt= '%.0f', inline = True) #Add labels
speed = np.sqrt(u**2+v**2) #Create speeds array
plt.barbs(x,y,u,v,speed) #Plot the wind barbs
plt.title('Brian\'s First Basemap')
m.drawcoastlines(color='black') #Draw coastlines
m.drawstates(color='green') #Draw States
m.drawcountries(color='gray') #Draw Countries
parallels = np.arange(0.,90,5.) #Create latitude reference lines every 5°
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10) #Draw latitude lines on map with preferences
meridians = np.arange(180.,360.,5.) #Create longitude reference lines every 5°
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10) #Draw longitude on map with preferences
plt.show()
#plt.savefig('Lab7_fig2.png', format='png') #Save your figure.  You should get the figure below. 

#Image(url= "Lab7_fig2.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

The example below illustrates how to 1) read a netCDF file, 2) save it as a zipped Numpy array, and 3) how to read back such a zipped array.

```
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc4

# Load example data:
nc = nc4.Dataset('drycblles.default.0000000.nc')
u = nc.variables["u"][:,:]

print(type(u), u.shape)

# Save array in .npz format:
np.savez('u.npz', u)

# Read the file back:
u_npz = np.load('u.npz')

# Get list of available arrays:
keys = u_npz.files
# Read the data (there is only one array):
u_2 = u_npz[keys[0]]

print(type(u_2), u_2.shape)
```

> `<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (8, 32)`
>
> `<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (8, 32)`

The problem might lie in how you save the zipped Numpy array. With e.g.

```
np.savez('u.npz', u)
```

Numpy automatically assigns the names (keys) `arr_0`, `arr_1`, etc:

```
u_npz = np.load('u.npz')    
keys = u_npz.files
print(keys)
```

> ['arr_0']

It is possible to provide names for the arrays that you are saving, e.g. with:

```
np.savez('u.npz', u_component=u)
```

`print(keys)` will give you:

> ['u_component']

So depending on what method was used for saving the `.npz` file, you have to read it as:

```
u_2 = u_npz['arr_0']
```

or

```
u_2 = u_npz['u_component']
```

Comment: Ok, but how does that work with two different netCDF files with the same variables? Your examples only draw from one file.

Comment: Could you explain that question a bit more? I don't see the difference between reading from 1, 2, or 100 files?

Comment: Oh, so in your example,you're combining 4 files? The periods act as commas?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. What part of my answer are you referring to?

Comment: nc = nc4.Dataset('drycblles.default.0000000.nc')